# Most Effective Method to Modify JArrays in JToken

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Seeking guidance on the most effective method to traverse a `JToken` object and modify every instance of a `JArray` object.

Specifically, I'm using the [JsonDiffPatch.net](https://github.com/wbish/jsondiffpatch.net) library to calculate the difference between two models, and then send only the changes over HTTP to a web client to patch the local state model.  To decrease the payload size, I'm removing the "left" data (as there will be no need to undo a patch).

Below is the code that I'm using now to perform this operation.

```
private static JToken CheckReplaceDiffArray(JToken obj)
{
    Boolean hasChanged = false;
    foreach (JToken content in obj.Values())
    {
        if (content.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            JToken newContent = CheckReplaceDiffArray(content);
            if (newContent != null)
            {
                content.Replace(newContent);
                hasChanged = true;
            }
        }

        if (content.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            JToken newContent = ReplaceDiffArrayFirst(content as JArray);
            if (newContent != null)
            {
                content.Replace(newContent);
                hasChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return hasChanged ? obj : null;
}
private static JArray ReplaceDiffArrayFirst(JArray obj)
{
    if (obj.Count > 1)
    {
        obj[0] = "";
        return obj;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You could always use [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JArray>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) rather than doing a manual traversal.  Watch out that you don't modify a collection while iterating through it however.  Other that that, what is your problem?  Do you have a bug or performance issue?

Comment: No problems specifically, just checking for input on if there may be a more efficient manner to perform it.  I haven't looked at the processing time of this individual operation yet, but performing the diff combined with this operation did consume quiet a bit of time for a large JSON object earlier.